# C: How to loop through a binary representation of a number and multiply

Tags: c, matrix

I have a long integer (ie 10001000110...) and an array with double values (ie {.5,.76,.34,...}) and I would like to loop through the binary representation of my integer and multiply each each digit with its corresponding place in my array and add it all together (matrix multiplication):

so like: 1*.5+0*.76+0*.34.....

whats best way to do this in C?

Thanks

Comment: Please identify homework as such by using the tag.  Also, an Nx1 matrix is usually called an array or vector, isn't it?

Comment: Is the most-significant bit of the integer multiplied by the `array[0]` value?  When you say 'long integer', do you mean `long int` (aka `long`), or are you talking about some 'BigNum' representation for the integer?  How do you know how many digits are in the long integer.  What if the long integer is a 32-bit unsigned value but the highest bit set is bit 16; do the bit elements of the array multiply a fixed position in the 32-bit (unsigned long integer) value, or is it relative to the first bit set?

Comment: This isn't for homework...and yes you can call an Nx1 matrix a vector or array.

Comment: So that integer is a mask of what numbers in the array should be added to the result.

Comment: I haven't really gotten to the point where I have the "integer" yet. I know my array will be of length 30. How could I store an integer so I have 30 available digits of 0s and 1s? Yes the integer is a sort of mask for the array.

Comment: @Benjamin Use a 32 bit integer, have a good grasp of hex IE `F = 1111`, `A = 1010`, `6 = 0110`. No all your binary <-> hex conversions for 0-F. Then you can say something like `uint32_t my_int = 0x3FFFFFFF` (30 1's).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
int n = n_doubles;
double result = 0.0;

while (n--) {
    if ((long_integer>>n)%2)
        result += doubles[n_doubles - n];
}
```

Comment: No it pairs the MSB with the element at index [0].

Comment: Oops - yes; I agree.  I'll withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the question is not clear, but from the latest comment of the author, it seems that it is about getting the bit representation of the integer.

First you have to use bitmasks to get a bitwise representation of the integer:

```
uint32_t theLongInt = <?>;
uint32_t mask = 0x00000001;

// bitwise representation of the integer theLongInt
uint8_t bits[30];

for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    if ( (theLongInt & mask) == 1)
        bits[i] = 1;
    else
        bits[i] = 0;
    mask = mask << 1;
}
```

Than you can loop to do the sum and multiply.

For increased efficiency, do not store the bitwise representation of the integer, but do the operations within a single for loop.

Comment: @buddhabrot way to get the value of each bit is much smarter than mine, which is academic. That should be the best answer :)!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to buddhabrot's answer, this more blatantly aligns bits and array elements, but aligns the LSB with with `index[0]`:

```
double result = 0.0;

for(int x=0; x<n_doubles; x++){
    if(long_integer & (1<<x))
          result += doubles[x];
}
```